# 404 when trying to load other template files when deploying angular app

Tags: angularjs

I have uploaded my angular app to my website.

When I try to acces it I get a 404 not found error on every possible file that the app is using. But the files are there so it should load it.

This is my project structure:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

The error:

> GET ****/views/templates/home.html 404 not found

Everything is working fine when I run it locally.

Comment: which web server are you running?

Comment: I'm deploying it on a subdomain of my website which is hosted on digitalocean (VPS)

Comment: Is there anyone with an answer?

Comment: it's unlikely; this isn't exactly a question that is a problem with anugular.  It's more likely that it's a problem with your hosting provider or the server technology they are using.  Their support would be your best resource, considering they are the only ones that can verify the files are indeed in the correct directories.